# Element is gone from the DOM, however, conditional statement still sees the element when using variables

Tags: javascript, html

Why when using the full JavaScript selector the 'if statement' of a interval for checking element existence works fine but when passing it as variable the IF statement thinks the element still exists, although, it doesn't?

Two examples to show the problem; first, the working version with full JS selectors:

```js
 
  var LoadMoreButton = document.querySelector('.loadMore');

  setInterval(function(){ LoadMoreButton.remove(); }, 10000);

  var timer = null;

  timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    console.log(LoadMoreButton);
    if (document.querySelector('.loadMore') !== null) {
      console.log("Element still exists, load more...");
      LoadMoreProducts();
    } else if(document.querySelector('.loadMore') === null) {
       console.log("Element does not exist.");
       StopLoadingProducts();
    }
  }, 1000);

  function LoadMoreProducts(){
    console.log("LoadMoreProducts Function ran");
  }

  function StopLoadingProducts(){
    console.log("No more products to load");
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log("End.");
  }
```

```html
<button class="loadMore">Load More</button>
```

And the not working version with variables. The console outputs the element even though the element is long gone!

```js
  var LoadMoreButton = document.querySelector('.loadMore');

  setInterval(function(){ LoadMoreButton.remove(); }, 10000);

  var timer = null;

  timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    console.log(LoadMoreButton);
    if (LoadMoreButton !== null) {
      console.log("Element still exists, load more...");
      LoadMoreProducts();
    } else if(LoadMoreButton === null) {
       console.log("Element does not exist.");
       StopLoadingProducts();
    }
  }, 1000);

  function LoadMoreProducts(){
    console.log("LoadMoreProducts Function ran");
  }

  function StopLoadingProducts(){
    console.log("No more products to load");
    clearInterval(timer);
    console.log("End.");
  }
```

```html
<button class="loadMore">Load More</button>
```

Why is my if statement not working when using the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because document.querySelector returns an object of HtmlElement that represents the first matching element in the dom. That object is not actually the dom element itself.

When calling `Element.remove()` you remove the node from the tree it belongs to, but the element itself remains in memory assigned to your variable `LoadMoreButton`. If you want the variable `LoadMoreButton` to be null after removing it from the dom, you can assign null to it.

```js
var LoadMoreButton = document.querySelector('.loadMore');

setInterval(function () {
  LoadMoreButton.remove();
  LoadMoreButton = null;
}, 10000);

var timer = null;

timer = window.setInterval(function () {
  if (LoadMoreButton !== null) {
    LoadMoreProducts();
  } else if (LoadMoreButton === null) {
    StopLoadingProducts();
  }
}, 1000);

function LoadMoreProducts() {}

function StopLoadingProducts() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}
```